# SSMS 18.8 and VS 2019 problems

Tags: visual-studio, ssms

Since a few days I am experiencing some weird issues with both SSMS and VS 2019:

- SSMS cannot open for editing any table (right click on table name) or design: the application hangs and becomes unresponsive.
- VS 2019 has become very very slow, opening windows takes a few second, compiling time for the same project has growth from 10 seconds to up to 1 minute (different projects tested)

No special errors in the Windows 10 Event Log, no other info.

Now I don't have many other details, I tried uninstalling and installing completely SSMS but didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Most find the designer isn't great in the first place. If you run the actual SQL statements, not use the designer, do that work? Using the SQL to make the alterations is *always* the preferred method.

Comment: Yes it works using the SQL statements. But I need the SSMS to be working like it's designed to!

Comment: Yes, I just discovered the same. The designer does not load table. It is a convenient place for simple work. Statement work. But, this should be fixed.

Comment: Also, I uninstalled 18.8, reinstalled 18.7.1 and I still can't use the designer

Comment: also having the same issue, any success with this?

Comment: I have contacted the Microsoft Support. They asked me to make some ordinary tests, but after more than one week still no resolution. I have the same problem on 2 different computers. So I guess it is some windows components. I am trying to dig it out, no luck so far. And it's getting annoying.

Comment: I have not had success, haven't seen anyone else but us comment on this. Haven't spent enough time figuring out how to roll back either.

Comment: I am still unable to get this working, has anyone had any success

Comment: Ever since I updated SSMS to 15.0.18358.0, I can't open a table for changes with the Design feature tool. The application becomes unresponsive. I updated again to 15.0.18369.0 and this did not resolve the problem. I too posted this to MS support

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for weeks and finally cleared out temp files and it now works.
(C:\Users\User Account\AppData\Local\Temp)